# JavaScript setTimeout simple error

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am learning JavaScript and got stuck on this simple piece of code that just won't work. I can probably find a different way of solving the task but really want to know why its not working as intended.

The two functions nyRuta and gommaRuta are called by onclick of html buttons. 
The idea is to open a new window and then to hide it for 3 seconds, after which it is returned to focus.

The window only hides, but doesn't reappear.

```
function nyRuta() {  
    lillaRutan = window.open('', '', 'width=200, height=100'); 
}

function gommaRuta (){ 
    lillaRutan.blur();
    setTimeout(show, 3000); //I have also tried this as an anonymous function

    function show (){ 
    lillaRutan.focus();
    }
}
```

Edit -  The function calls are as below:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="nyRuta()"> Open</button> 
 <button type="button" onclick="gommaRuta()">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Where are the function calls?

Comment: From html, as specified in the text above.
<button type="button" onclick="nyRuta()"> Open</button>
<button type="button" onclick="gommaRuta()">Hide</button>

Comment: Where is `lillaRutan` defined?

Comment: Most likely `newWindow.focus()` doesn't bring the window back to life after `newWindow.blur()`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur) `blur()` is not a standard function. Most likely in the browser you're using it it is not implemented. Anyway without a jsfiddle/planker it would hard to help

Comment: See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/ysnwy0jx/1/) that includes your code. I noticed that timeout method works only when timeout is <=1000. For delays more then 1000 ms the window doesn't show up again. I think this is some browser security measure. Will continue research

Comment: Just a note, even if your language is not, your code should always be in English (variable names, function names)